# How to reload by resetting pagination, total rows in DataTable plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am not sure on how to reload a new table with the correct pagination and etc when every time i insert a new Data or select a different dropdown option.

What my usual code does is, when i select a value from my dropdown, my table will refresh and display a new set of data inside the table body tag. When i use this plugin, it displays everything perfectly fine but when i select a different value from my dropdown, it displays a new set but my sorting, pagination and others will still function based on the first set of data i selected.

Here is my code. It will really be helpful if someone can point out my mistake. Thank you !

```
var loadClassType = function(eventID){
    $("#loadClassTypeTableBody").empty();

    var formData = {
        'perform'     : "getClassTypeList",
        'event_id'    : eventID,
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : './competition.php', 
        data        : formData, 
        dataType    : 'json', 
        encode      : true
    })
    .done(function(data) {

        if (data.success) {
            var htmlBlock="";
            var i = 1;
            $.each(data.data, function(id,errMsg){
                htmlBlock += '<tr>';
                htmlBlock +=    '<td>'+i+'</td>';
                htmlBlock +=    '<td>'+errMsg['class_type_name']+'</td>';

                if (errMsg['status'] == 1 ) {
                      htmlBlock +=    '<td class="text-success">Active</td>';               
                }else{
                      htmlBlock +=    '<td class="text-danger">Disabled</td>';
                }

                if (errMsg['status'] == 1 ) {
                      htmlBlock +=    '<td><i class="material-icons" rel="tooltip" title data-original-title="Click to \'Disable\'" onClick="ctrlClassType(2,'+errMsg['id']+','+eventID+')">lock_open</i></td>';                
                }else{
                      htmlBlock +=    '<td><i class="material-icons" rel="tooltip" title data-original-title="Click to \'Enable\' " onClick="ctrlClassType(1,'+errMsg['id']+','+eventID+')">lock</i></td>';
                }
                htmlBlock +=  '</tr>';
                i++;
        });



            $("#loadClassTypeTableBody").append(htmlBlock);
            $("#loadClassTypeTable").DataTable().clear();
        }else{
            console.log(data);

        } 
    });
}
```

And my HTML Code :

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="loadClassTypeTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Class Type Name</th>

            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="loadClassTypeTableBody">
      <!-- Depends on JS -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What i have tried so far is,

```
$("#loadClassTypeTable").DataTable().clear().draw(); 
// returns "No data available in table" and following with my blocks of html code
$("#loadClassTypeTable").DataTable().ajax.reload(); // doesnt work because i am not passing a jason value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after spending sometime, i found a fix by playing around with the codes and doing some research. This method worked for me. Hopefully it might help someone who encountered the same problem as mine.

**First thing to take note :**

```
//clear and destroy the table first
$('#viewEntriesTable').DataTable().clear();
$('#viewEntriesTable').DataTable().destroy(); 

//in my case,i will use the append method to insert my HTML Blocks of code first 
$("#load_total_joined_entries").append(htmlBlocks);

//and finally 
 $('#viewEntriesTable').DataTable();
```

**Second thing to take note:** I have to avoid appending my html blocks if there is no rows detected by using "colspan" ... this was referred from [the discussion here](http://[https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined][1]) after getting an error which says *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined datatable*